# JavaScript - Prevent cut and paste by drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, copy-paste, contenteditable

I want to prevent the following behavior on a contenteditable div, because it messes with the structure if the div contains any other elements but text nodes.

[image]

I have tried the obvious:

1. Setting draggable="false" on the div
2. Calling preventDefault on the dragstart and drop events (event listeners also on the div)

However, this does not seem to work and I want to allow regular pasting, so disabling that is not an option.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say that's not possible with a contenteditable

Comment: @ChrisG This functionality used to be disabled in VS Code. AFAIK VS Code is based on Electron and therefore probably also uses a contenteditable div internally. So there probably is some way to do so.

Comment: @ChrisG Can confirm.

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault` on `ondragover` should prevent this behaviour.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondragover.asp